# PDT how to open html file as php?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Tried this: [Eclipse PDT isn't highlighting PHP syntax in .html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319708/eclipse-pdt-isnt-highlighting-php-syntax-in-html-files/4319759#4319759)
But there no any "PHP Content type".

How to open in eclipse .html file as PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

have you the web tools package installed? you can find it at http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

also see [this reference](http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=180) for how to add file types to your php editor.

or just

1. Go to Window > Preferences
2. In Preferences, go to General > Content Types
3. Select PHP Source File and add *.html as a file association
4. Click on File Associations link on General > Editors > File
   Associations
5. Select *.html and add the PHP Editor as an associated editor - make
   it the default

Comment: I can't select PHP Source File at Contents Types, because there no this element in list...

Comment: it should be if you have the web tools package installed

Answer (score 1):

Checked, but all file extensions seemed to be ok in my eclipse PDT.  Finally copied all, pasted the file into notepad++, saved it to a new name, did F5 in eclipse ... and it came up fine... I assume some characters were strange and the copy and paste to NP++ fixed that.