# How to highlight php and javascript functions inside HTML in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse

Is there a way to highlight the JavaScript and PHP functions inside HTML in Eclipse Juno? I tried connecting to some of the repositories but it is not giving me the results that I want. I just want to distinguish the functions from boring text. Thanks.

Comment: Try following this answer:[Highlight php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319708/eclipse-pdt-isnt-highlighting-php-syntax-in-html-files

Comment: Nope, did not work either. but thanks for answering.

Comment: I advice you to install PHP Development tools, it is a possible solution.@ladybug